# What are the potential issues when removing interleaved tables from CockroachDB?

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

With interleaving being deprecated in Cockroach v21, I have some tables that I'm trying to alter. These exist in a hierarchy with the primary of each being interleaved into its parent. No secondary indexes appear to be interleaved.

I followed the recommended process for de-interleaving these (running an `alter primary key` with the original components and omitting the interleave) but when the migration was applied, I got an error stating that the job couldn't be completed and that manual cleanup might be required. I wound up having to restore from backup.

Are there any gotchas around de-interleaving tables? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry that that happened. That implies that there's a bug somewhere. It'd be great if you could file a github issue with some more details so that we can figure out what happened and get to the bottom of it. Ideally we can prevent somebody else from running into whatever you hit.

You can you [this link](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/new?assignees=&labels=C-bug&template=bug_report.md&title=) to file the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've filed an issue.